# Android listview issues

Tags: java, android, listview

I am developing a Android application. From my main activity I would navigate to a second one, which would display some data in the form of a listview. My problem consists in addind a ArrayAdapter to the listview and adding the ListView to the activities content.

My second activities xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/doctorslistview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

The activity is called: activity_doctors.

Code behind:

```
public class Doctors extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctors);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ArrayList<Doctor> docs = null;

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    try {
        String doctors = GetDoctorsFromServer();

        docs = GetDoctorsListFromServerString(doctors);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView myListView = new ListView(this);

    String[] docsArray = new String[docs.size() + 1];

    int i = 0;
    for(Doctor d : docs)
    {
        docsArray[i] = d.getDoctorName();
        i++;
    }

    myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_doctors,
             R.id.doctorslistview, docsArray));


    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_doctors, docsArray));


    setContentView(myListView);
}
```

The error occurres when the last instruction is executed: setContentView(myListView);

Stack trace:

```
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298): Process: com.example.cabinetmedical.android, PID: 24298
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2452)
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1891)
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:792)
02-17 21:51:48.639: E/AndroidRuntime(24298):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:853)
```

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Comment: one of the elements in docsArray is null (because docsArray.size() = docs.size() + 1) but it is just a bling guessing ... try to learn how to use debugger ... and messing with thread policy is really stupid idea

Comment: Great catch. I didn't even think about looking there for the error. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L394 => `item.toString() == NPE` => `item == null`

Comment: A note because you seem new, methods (such as GetDoctorsFromServer) should not begin with capitals

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do this, you are using setContentView twice. What is inside activty_doctors.xml? There should be a ListView item that you will bind to it with getListView or findViewById.